# Creating a nested dictionary with grouping the elements of list

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a list that contains the teams of schools

```
Teams = [["ThomasJeffersonHC", "Lucy"],
         ["ThomasJeffersonHC", "Elliot"],
         ["ThomasJeffersonHC", "Noah"],
         ["GilbertHC", "Kyle"],
         ["ThomasJeffersonHC", "Liam"],
         ["GilbertHC", "Bradley"],
         ["GilbertHC", "Eugene"]]
```

trying to group them in a dictionary by the first element of inner lists.

the dic's template be like below:

```
d  = {"School_key": {"members": [group members list], "count": count of members }}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the Teams list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
d = {}
lastkey = None
for key, member in Teams:
    if key != lastkey:
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {1: {"members": [member], "count": 1}}
        else:
            number = max(d[key]) + 1
            d[key][number] = {"members": [member], "count": 1}
        lastkey = key
    else:
        number = max(d[key])
        d[key][number]["members"].append(member)
        d[key][number]["count"] += 1
print(d)
```

In this code, first I set `d` to an empty dict. Then I iterated through the `Teams` list, for every key if it is the same as the previous one I add a member to the pre-existing team, otherwise I create a new team and add the member into the team.